# Case.object (Case.QuestionId) -- Error: fullName must end with: __c or __kav or __x or __b or __xo or __e or __p or __mdt

Tags: migration

I'm trying to script CI using the Salesforce Migration API at the non profit I volunteer at. We use NPSP. My build keeps failing with the following error ( there are several of these with what I believe to be standard fields ).

> Case.object (Case.QuestionId) -- Error: fullName must end with: __c or
>   __kav or __x or __b or __xo or __e or __p or __mdt

I'm trying to re-create content from our Sandbox organization in a dev org. i.e the Case object I'm trying to deploy to dev was retrieved from a Sandbox org.

I see these errors on several standard objects and fields ( Case.SourceID, Case.CommunityId ) . Is this some kind of permissioning thing ?

All help appreciated ..

Comment: Why are you trying to migrate standard fields?

Comment: The standard fields appear in our sandbox but not in my ( newly minted ) dev org.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the doc it seems

> QuestionID field does not appear if you don't have an answers community enabled

So some of these requires you to enable specific features in your orgs for the fields to appear .

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to enable answers community using the migration api ?

Comment: Not that I know off.Salesforce DX once comes should resolve these problems where one can spin orgs with this feature enabled .For now manual

Comment: Thanks Mohith. I have a follow up question. It sounds like Chatter Answers is deprecated [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Chatter-Answers-to-Retire-in-Winter-18]. And Chatter Answers aren't available in new orgs starting Summer '16. Does this imply that a standard "Questions" object isn't available in new orgs ?

Comment: You can try querying .I think they are available .May be only that reference field is deprecated .